# How to use multi WPF ResourceDictionary separately in one WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing a WPF application and I want to use UI libraries, I found "ModernWpfUI" and "HandyControl" in visual studio NuGet and I have installed them. Now I want to use them in one WPF window separately. For example I want to have two Slider in a window which the first one has "ModernWpfUI" style and the second has "HandyControl" style.

for this I added

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ui:ThemeResources />
                <ui:XamlControlsResources />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HandyControl;component/Themes/SkinDefault.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/HandyControl;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

to my .xaml file and then I added

```
<Slider Orientation="Vertical" Margin="309,48,444,98" ></Slider>
        <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Margin="413,48,340,98"></Slider>
```

but now both of them have same style ("HandyControl" style).
how can I have

```
        <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Margin="309,48,444,98" ></Slider>
        <!---- With HandyControl style-->
        <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Margin="413,48,340,98"></Slider>
        <!---- With ModernWpfUI style-->
```

Comment: The idea of theme is to easily *switch* them and not to use at the same time. You can do something extremelly inefficient (memory-wise): add specific theme to resources of container of control (or maybe control itself). It may be possible to create an extension/behavior to have only 2 instances loaded (try that if container resource works). But adding two themes to merged dictionaries of application clearly doesn't make sense: only one will be used.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is that both ModernWpfUI and HandyControl are using implicit styles for the `Slider` control.

That is, their styles are applied to the type vs. a style key. So the last one defined in your resources wins. In this case HandyControl.

To use both styles, you'll need to use an explicit style key for each one. You can get the style key by looking at their XAML.

It would look something like this:

```
<Slider Orientation="Vertical" Margin="309,48,444,98" Style="{DynamicResource WhatEverHandlyControlStyleIs}" />
<!---- With HandyControl style-->

<Slider Orientation="Vertical" Margin="413,48,340,98" Style="{DynamicResource DefaultSliderStyle}" />
<!---- With ModernWpfUI style-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Style` property of each control explicitly to the `Style` you want to apply. This should work:

```
<!---- With HandyControl style-->
<Slider Style="{StaticResource SliderBaseStyle}" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="309,48,444,98" />

<!---- With ModernWpfUI style-->
<Slider Style="{StaticResource DefaultSliderStyle}" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="413,48,340,98"/>
```